# How To disable This Page?

Tags: 18.04, login-screen

How to disable this page?

[image]

It opens at StartUp.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to clarify: Do you want to be logged in automatically? Or do you want to use another [display manager](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/choose-switch-linux-display-managers/)? Or even a [textual login screen](http://i.imgur.com/XtvXhye.png)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an automatic login without password, open the settings (top right corner, then choose the screwdriver icon), select 'details', 'users', 'unlock' with your password and switch the 'Automatic Logon' to 'ON'.

Comment: Your answer is about LightDM greeter while the OP has a kind of xinit / xdm greeter.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your XDM greeter back to standard LightDM one with commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm --reinstall
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm # click OK on 1st screen, select lightdm on 2nd
```

[image: Default display manager]

and reboot.